# after installing react-native-paystack-webview and running build, build fails with compileDebugAndroidTestKotlin error

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, build.gradle, paystack

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':tasks'.

> Could not create task ':react-native-paystack-webview:compileDebugAndroidTestKotlin'.
> Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method AbstractKotlinCompile.execute() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method

i tried uninstalling and running build again, that works fine, and when i install while on the app, it works fine too but fails to compile when i try to rebuild, this happens on only ANDROID, it works perfectly on IOS

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Add KotlinVersion to your build.gradle file